# Android Studio Newb - autocomplete or just incorrectly installed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to learn Android Studio / Java for the first time. I am familiar with c#, vb.net, javascript and a few other languages.

The [video: Android Studio for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFlPARW5IX8) I am following, at 22:56 shows auto completion happening... However I am not getting anything, if I press CTRL+space I get nothing, and the IDE is throwing an error as below, and pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAPWl.jpg)

> Function invocation 'Button(...)' expected None of the following
>   functions can be called with the arguments supplied. (Context!)
>   defined in android.widget.Button (Context!, AttributeSet!)
>   defined in android.widget.Button (Context!, AttributeSet!, Int)
>   defined in android.widget.Button (Context!, AttributeSet!, Int,
>   Int) defined in android.widget.Button

I suspect I have Android Studio set up wrong, or missing a component/ plugin.
As a complete Newb, I also set it up from scratch, ie. installed it on Windows 10 x64 machine.

What should I check?
I have

- installed Java, Java JDK
- reinstalled studio
- checked on the autocomplete settings
- refreshed cache

Comment: Just make sure you're using the latest version of android studio and allow it update plugins where necessary if it requests for it.

Comment: no problem @GiddyNaya, just saying you should have checked it a bit closer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple:

That is not Java, it is Kotlin (https://kotlinlang.org/)

Try to recreate the project from scratch, just check the project configuration carefully when you create it (there should be check box to add support for kotlin or not at the start) to ensure that you are making JAVA files and NOT Kotlin files (Kotlin ends with .kt).

Alternatively, delete this MainActivity and create a new Java MainActivity OR , to get you started, with Kotlin the syntax would have been :

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yourButtonID)
```

---

*(this is entirely my own opinion, but I almost want to recommend that you just find a Kotlin tutorial instead, with your mixed background, Kotlin could potentially be an easier start, and also because Kotlin is so much nicer :P but this is my own opinion)*

Comment: Thanks, I like opinions :) I will try it out.... any suggestions for a Kotlin tutorials?

Comment: not really, i learned the hard way, I just started doing it :D it's a really cool language but i had java experience when learning it, with your mixed background i think it would fit you better than pure java. (i'm very sad that someone downvoted my answer, it most definitely IS the right answer though)

Comment: btw I also wrote to the video creator and they confirmed this :)
I haven't had a chance to go back to it, new weekend hobby. :)

Comment: no problem, I wish I could be like you to learn different languages all the time, but kotlin-android is really all I need to keep me happy :D I've done a bit of web and c# and a few others, but yeah, android with kotlin is all I need, if anything i'd want to learn Node and Express.js, but this is very off topic :D happy coding @CraigLambie

Comment: Haha, expert in one vs hack in many... I think you are right in being great with 1.